# File is uploaded even when IP not in the list of allowed IPs

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

When I type any IP in API access information and trying to upload file for softlayer via API call - file is uploaded. Why I don't get "access denied"?

Comment: Is that happening only when you upload files? what about other services or methods? can you share your resquest?

Comment: It happened when I try to upload/download file to objectStorage

$objectStorage->with('container/filename')
                ->setLocalFile('filePath')
                ->setHeader('Content-type', 'content type of the file')
                ->setMeta('description', 'Some description')
                ->create();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API access retriction is only for the [Softlayer API](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/softlayerapi) and not for the [Object Storage API](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/objectstorageapi).

Regards